# Flutter IOS generate application release from xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, app-store, flutter-ios

I can't generate **application release on Xcode for ios**  ( for **testing purposes** not to publish ) [ipa archive file]

> note 1: I **didn't purchase** the annual 99$ membership of the **app store**
> is it a must to generate a release ??
>
> note 2: I **don't have ios real device** I'm just using an **emulator**, is a
> real ios device a must to generate the release version even for
> testing

here is what I get on Xcode :
[image]

Comment: I don't think you can build IPA without an Apple Developer Account and Provisioning profile.

Comment: You need to have one device registered in your account in order to create a provisioning profile. You need a provisioning profile to create an ad-hoc archive.  Without a real device there is no point in creating an archive since you can only run the build on the device(s) contained in the provisioning profile. To get a build that runs on any device you need to submit it to Apple for review and loading into the App Store; this requires a paid membership.

Comment: thank you, I understand that I need to have a paid membership on Appel  app store and a real ios device ! is it true ?